# In C, I'm having trouble getting the pointed value of a member struct(a double pointer). The value is lost outside the function assigning the value

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

typedef struct {
  double *presult;
} SomeData;

//Fonction that assigns the value to be pointed
void  *assignValue(void *data) {
    SomeData *aData = (SomeData*)data;
    double valeurTotal = 45.50;

    aData->presult = &valeurTotal; //Make the pointer point to the value

    printf("%10.3f \n",*aData->presult); //Here it prints the right answer L 45.50
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    SomeData myData; // The struct
    pthread_t onethread; 
    pthread_create(&onethread, NULL, assignValue,(void *)&myData); 
    pthread_join(onethread, NULL);

    printf("**************************************** \n");
    printf("%10.3f \n", (myData.presult)); // prints: 0
    printf("%10.3f \n", *(myData.presult));// prints: 0

    exit(0);
}
```

Question might be confusing, so hopefully this simplified version of my code can explain better. So basically, I've created a thread that modifies the values of a struct.

Inside the thread function, the struct is passed-on as a pointer. One of the struct's member is a double pointer 'presult'. The thread function makes the 'presult' point to a value and it seems to work, because the print works.

However, back into the main function, I try to print the value of 'presult' again, but it doesn't print 45.50, but 0.0 instead.

In my full code, I actually get Segmentation fault with the last print. But even in this simplified code, it doesn't work. It doesn't print 45.50.

Output is as followed:

```
45.50
****************************************
0.000
0.000
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: `double valeurTotal` is created on the function stack of `assignValue` its *address* no longer exists after the function returns. (leading to *Undefined Behavior* when you attempt to access the value at an address that is no longer valid) Don't assign the address, simply allocate storage for `presult` and assign the value, e.g. `*aData->presult = valeurTotal;` (or change `double *presult;` to `double presult;`) Unless you are intending to point to an array, it costs 8-bytes regardless whether it is a pointer or a `double`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
double valeurTotal = 45.50;
aData->presult = &valeurTotal; //Make the pointer point to the value
```

The memory location assigned to `valeurTotal` is going to be reused when `assignValue` goes out scope.

This is most likely the case at

```
printf("%10.3f \n", *(myData.presult)); // prints: 0
```

Also at this line you're trying to print a pointer as a floating number, which is wacky.

```
printf("%10.3f \n", (myData.presult)); // prints: 0
```

You need to actually store the value in your structure, which you can do by

```
typedef struct {
  double presult; // will copy into this when its assigned.
} SomeData;
```

Obviously, if you only wanted one double value you'd just pass that double as a pointer rather than a strucutre.